# Duda en consulta SQL group by y nulls

Tags: sql, group-by

Fiddle para probar consultas:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7d092/2

> Pongamos que tengo una tabla así.

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|     Cod     |  Provincia  |    Cliente       |     tlfn    |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|   00001     |  Barcelona  |   Cliente1       |  666123123  |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|   00002     |  Pais Vasco |   Cliente2       |  666345345  |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|   00003     |  Madrid     |   Cliente3       |  952819252  |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|   00004     |  Valencia   |   Cliente4       |  895182952  |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|   00005     |  Barcelona  |   Cliente5       |  666213213  |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
```

> Y le hago esta consulta.

```
SELECT Provincia, COUNT(*)
FROM tabla
WHERE tlfn LIKE '666%'
GROUP BY Provincia
```

> El resultado de esta consulta sería

```
+------------+-------+
| Barcelona  |   2   |
+------------+-------+
| Pais vasco |   1   |
+------------+-------+
```

Pero además quiero que también **se refleje** que en **Madrid** y en **Valencia no hay** ningún cliente cuyo teléfono **empiece por** 666

¿Como puedo reflejar eso en el resultado?
¿Como consigo este resultado?

```
+------------+-------+
| Barcelona  |   2   |
+------------+-------+
| Pais vasco |   1   |
+------------+-------+
|  Valencia  |   0   |
+------------+-------+
|  Madrid    |   0   |
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Si no tienes una tabla en la que figuren las demás provincias no lo puedes hacer. Dos tablas, una de provincias y otra de clientes. Una select con join de ambas tablas te dará el resultado deseado.

Comment: ¿De ninguna forma? Es que en mi caso no tengo nada así, simplemente es la tabla cuya clave es "provincia" en este caso, aunque en la tabla real representa otro dato, ¿Con subselect o algo?

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, tengo mal formada la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Así, muy rápido se me ocurre esto.

```
SELECT tabla.Provincia,count(conDatos.Provincia)
FROM tabla  LEFT OUTER JOIN  
 (select distinct Provincia from tabla WHERE tabla.Telefono LIKE '666%') conDatos   ON
conDatos.provincia=tabla.provincia
group by tabla.Provincia
order by Provincia
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/470c1/1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora solo me queda trasladar esto a 44 consultas distintas :)

Comment: Si puedes usa Procedimientos Almacenados, quizás poniendo un par de parámetros que dinámicamente construyan la query te ahorres trabajo. Ya sabes, ser vago luego sale rentable :)

Comment: El problema es que no me conozco la BBDD sobre la que trabajo, los campos están en francés y pues bueno, son cosas muy distintas, de todas formas gracias.